# Running scheduled task in current profile with another user

Tags: windows, backup, scheduled-task, batch-file

I have a doubt about Windows scheduler: I created a domain user (*backupuser*) appositely to launch a batch file that starts the backup. The problem is that the batch is launched in the "*backupuser*" profile and it is not shown to the current user. How can I make sure that it is started as *backupuser* (profile which does not undergo a change of password) and it is displayed by the current user? I do not know if I have explained. 
Thanks!

Comment: The OS is Windows XP Pro SP3 in NT4 Domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use a log file and have the bat job email it to yourself using a tool like blat or bmail

Or

- Execute the bat using psexec -s -i backup.bat. The command window will appear on the current users desktop. BEWARE the bat will run as SYSTEM user.

Comment: Great!!! The second solution is what I was searching for! Thank you very much!